# onTap event in overlay

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Anyone who can help me to implement ontap() event using this code?
        That code below will display the current location of the user's and bar
        location in google map. that code works fine. but my problem is I don't know on how
        to implement ontap() event. Is it posible to implement onTap event even my overlay
        is outside of oncreate bundle?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
    import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
    import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;



    public class BarLocatorActivity extends MapActivity {
         Button map1,login1,menu1,power1;        
        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONNorman jNorman = new JSONNorman();


        private static String url_all_bar =
      "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xampp/BARANDROID/get_all_bars.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_BARS = "bars";
        private static final String TAG_BARLAT = "bar_lat";
        private static final String TAG_BARLONG = "bar_long";

        // bars JSONArray
        JSONArray bars = null;


        private MapController mapController;
        private MapView mapView;
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;

        public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.map); // bind the layout to the activity

        // Configure the Map
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        // enable Street view by default
        mapView.setStreetView(true);

       // mapView.setSatellite(true);

        // enable to show Traffic on map
        // mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15); // Zoon 1 is world view
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

        myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

        myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {

            mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
          }
        });
        new LoadAllBars().execute();
      }

      /* Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml) */
      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
      {
          MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
          menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
          return true;
      }

      /**
       * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
       * Identify single menu item by it's id
       * */
      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
      {

          switch (item.getItemId())
          {

          case R.id.view:
              BarLocatorActivity.this.finish();
              Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                   AllBarActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent1);
              android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(0);
              return true;

          case R.id.map1:
              BarLocatorActivity.this.finish();
              Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BarLocatorActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent2);
              android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(0);
              return true;

          case R.id.login:
              BarLocatorActivity.this.finish();
              Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                  SignInActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent3);
                  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(0); 
                return true;

          case R.id.exit:                       
                        BarLocatorActivity.this.finish();   
                        // The following makes the Android Gods frown upon me
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                        System.exit(0);         
              return true;
          default:
              return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
      }

      public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
          int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
          GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);  
          mapController.animateTo(point); // mapController.setCenter(point);

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
      }



      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
        myLocationOverlay.disableCompass();
      }



    //bar location
      class LoadAllBars extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
          protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

              List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
              JSONObject json = jNorman.makeHttpRequest(url_all_bar, "GET", params);

              Log.d("All bars: ", json.toString());

              try {
                  // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                  int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                  if (success == 1) {
                      bars = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BARS);                   

                      for (int i = 0; i < bars.length(); i++) {                     
                          JSONObject c = bars.getJSONObject(i);
                          String bar_lat = c.getString(TAG_BARLAT);  
                          String bar_long = c.getString(TAG_BARLONG);  
                          double latt = Double.parseDouble(bar_lat);
                          double lngg = Double.parseDouble(bar_long);

                        GeoPoint points = new GeoPoint((int) (latt * 1E6),(int) (lngg * 
                        1E6));
                        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                    mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(points);
                    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();           
                    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
                          }                     
                  }     

              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

              return null;
          }  
      }

      //end bar location

      //overlay

      class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint points) {
            pointToDraw = points;
        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
            return pointToDraw;
        }

          @Override
          public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
              super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

              // convert point to pixels
              Point screenPts = new Point();
              mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);
              // add marker
              Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
              canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null);          
              return true;
          }  
      } 

    } 

    thanks in advance:)
```